# Simplify INSERTION syntax on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have form like this
[PO form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14Wc.png)
on the second part of the form, user can input one to eight data at max, here's my insertion code:

```
Sub input_item1()
    If TB_Item1.Text <> "" Then
        With cmd2a
            con.Open()
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO po_details (po_number, date, item_name, quantity, unit, price, discount, total_price) VALUES (@numb, @date, @item, @qty, @unit, @price, @disc, @total)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numb", (TB_PoNumb.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DT1.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", (TB_Item1.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", TB_qty1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", (TB_unit1.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", (TB_Price1.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@disc", (TB_Disc1.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (TB_total1.Text).ToUpper)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

for item number 2

```
Sub input_item2()
    If TB_Item2.Text <> "" Then
        With cmd2b
            con.Open()
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO po_details (po_number, date, item_name, quantity, unit, price, discount, total_price) VALUES (@numb, @date, @item, @qty, @unit, @price, @disc, @total)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numb", (TB_PoNumb.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DT1.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", (TB_Item2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", TB_qty2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", (TB_unit2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", (TB_Price2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@disc", (TB_Disc2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (TB_total2.Text).ToUpper)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

and I keep rewrite the code 8 times matched the number of the max items, is there anyway to simplify this?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The DataGridView was pretty much made for things like that.  No code needed beyond one line to `Update` if you configure a DataAdapter as well.  Otherwise you could put the code in a method and pass FooBar1 or FooBar2 etc

Comment: interesting, any reference i can follow?

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix but, ignoring that, the answer would be to put the common code into a single method and then all you have to do is call that method inside each `If` statement.

Comment: When someone gives you a keyword like `DataGridView`, your very first action should be to search the web and more specifically, the MSDN web site for information using that keyword. Don't expect others to explain things to you that you can find for yourself. Look first, ask questions later.

Comment: With regards to refactoring the common code into its won method, the setting of the "@item" parameter is still common and you can just pass in the `TextBox` or its `Text` as a parameter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney got it. sorry about that, i'm looking for that.I'll be back if I found another problem

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are better ways to handle this, as suggested in the comments, I figured that I'd provide an answer to the question as asked, because the principle may be relevant on other occasions. The thing to do is to extract the common code into its own method with the different parts extracted as parameters, e.g.

```
Sub input_item(cmd As SqlCommand, TB_Item As TextBox)
    If TB_Item.Text <> "" Then
        With cmd
            con.Open()
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO po_details (po_number, date, item_name, quantity, unit, price, discount, total_price) VALUES (@numb, @date, @item, @qty, @unit, @price, @disc, @total)"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numb", (TB_PoNumb.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DT1.Value)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", (TB_Item.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", TB_qty2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", (TB_unit2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", (TB_Price2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@disc", (TB_Disc2.Text).ToUpper)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", (TB_total2.Text).ToUpper)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

and then call that method and pass the appropriate arguments as needed.

Comment: No, the common thing to do is use a class... The data shouldnt know about the UI, and by passing controls to handle the data is wrong IMO.

Comment: Of course separation of data access and presentation code is preferable but that goes rather beyond the scope of this question, which is specifically about how to avoid repeating code. Pick your battles.

Comment: wait, I'm not quite get it with, can you elaborate please? why is it only TB_item you declared?

Comment: Ah, I just realised that all the other controls are different too.  I thought that they were the same.  That just means more parameters though.  It also means that using a grid is an even better idea.